# Can I use a ST-LINK V2 as a universal JTAG or TTL serial interface?

Tags: stm32, serial, ttl, jtag, st-link

I have a ST Link V2 as pictured below. I would like to use it as a general purpose JTAG and or Serial TTL USB interface for communicating with a wide variety of devices. The documentation claims it supports SWM, which appears to be JTAG, but it's unclear if it is a vendor specific version of the standard.

Since the ST Link V2 has built-in firmware to function, I'm assuming its not just a dumb interface and may require additional steps to make it work.  Can this be used for my purpose or should I just get a general purpose JTAG cable?  If so, what's entailed?

[image: ST-LINK V2]

Comment: PJ answered probably, but yes you can use it with non-ST arm microcontrollers.  It is more of an openocd support for that other microcontroller thing.  Have had success with some and problems with others.

Comment: I prefer a generic ftdi breakout board like the adafruit FT232H one, you can do SWD and UART.  (or JTAG and UART for full sized things like the raspberry pi).

Comment: I managed to use an arduino as a UART and it works well. It requires taking over the UART from the MCU. The mega has several UART ports to play with. I would investigate using it for JTAG, but I figured I already have the ST-LINK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **it is not** an JTAG probe. It is the ARM SWD debugger probe. Probably you can use it with non STM32 ARM microcontrollers using openOCD. .

This probe does not have UART <> USB converter you of course can't use it.  You need ST-LINK V2/1